# Scrolling Only Works With Keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, tumblr

On this Tumblr theme that I'm working on, the default setting is to only allow horizontal scrolling. I changed that by applying

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('iframe').each(function(){
              $(this).attr('scrolling','yes');
       });
})
```

Now, the scrolling works vertically, but only by using the keyboard. It doesn't allow scrolling by the mouse. Is there a setting to change that?

Example: http://reluctanttrading.tumblr.com/

Comment: Can you share an example of the site you are having an issue with?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1rHCEib

Comment: Scrolling seems to work fine with a mouse: http://i.imgur.com/7ixfOSi.png If its still an issue, I would update the question with the browser and more specific details.

Comment: yeah for me it works with the mouse and without keyboard

Comment: Vertical scrolling on the home page does not work with mouse.